# "QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1"

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qpainter

I have the following test code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
painter = QPainter(widget)
```

Upon creating the QPainter object, I get the error message:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
```

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to draw something inside a widget, you need to use the `paintEvent` of the widget to define a `QPainter`. This method allows to declare a `Qpainter` for an immediat painting, and by the way it avoids a call to `Qpainter.begin()` and `Qpainter.end()`.

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#details

> Warning: When the paintdevice is a widget, QPainter can only be used inside a paintEvent() function or in a function called by paintEvent().